# Can i create/view opportunity without having Salesforce licence?

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, licenses, userlicense

Is there any way to create/view opportunity or other standard objects which are not allowed in my salesforce licence ? like can i use inbound email serices to create opportunity record or running code in system context will allow me to create/view standard objects which are not mentioned in my Salesforce Licence or is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a way to avoid permission limits due to context is to create an inbound email service. Email Service run in system context so you can create opportunity with it. I have used this trick to sync data between a custom object and a standard object, not writable on a Site running as anonymous.